# Pyplot stacking all values on an axis in one position

Tags: matplotlib

The pyplot figure I'm generating is stacking all values of a list on a single position. Is there any explanation for this?

To reproduce:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0.85, 0.87])
ax.scatter(n_vec, te_scores, color=(0,0,1,0.3), s=100)
# ax.scatter(n, tr_scores, color=(1,0,0,0.3), s=100)
ax.set_aspect(1)
```

[image: figure with result]

For reference, n_vec is a list of integers ranging from 100 to 100,000 and te_scores is a list of integers ranging from 0.85 to 0.87.

I've tried setting limits to the y axis and increasing the number of decimal places on the ticks but neither of those caused the y axis to unstack.

Answer (score 1):

> `n_vec` is a list of integers ranging from 100 to 100,000 and `te_scores` is a list of <s>integers</s> *floats* ranging from 0.85 to 0.87

Then you should not set the aspect of the axis to 1. This will generate the squashed figure that you have
[Checkout the set_aspect doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html)

You're code without the `ax.set_aspect(1)`

```py
n_vec = np.random.randint(100, 100000, size=100)
te_scores = 0.85 + np.random.rand(100) * 2 / 100

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0.85, 0.87])
ax.scatter(n_vec, te_scores, color=(0, 0, 1, 0.3), s=100)
```

The result:

[image]